# Properties of product of symmetric P.S.D matrices

Tags: matrices, linear-algebra

If I have a symmetric positive semidefinite matrix $R$ and a column vector $x$, with $0\leq x^TRx \leq x^Tx$, empirically with simulations, I found that:
$$
(x^TR^{-1}x)(x^TRx) \geq (x^Tx)^2
$$
I wonder if it's possible to show this.

What if we know that every element of $x$ is positive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As $R$ is positive semidefinite, it is diagonalisable, so we may assume it
is diagonal. Let its
diagonal entries are $r_1,\ldots, r_n$. Each $r_i\ge0$, but as you are
dealing with $R^{-1}$, each $r_i>0$. As $x^t Rx\le x^tx$ we have $r_i\le1$
too. Then for $x=(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$,
$$(x^tR^{-1}x)(x^tRx)=\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{x_i^2}{r_i}\sum_{j=1}^n r_jx_j^2.$$ By Cauchy-Schwarz, this is
$$\ge\left(\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{x_i}{\sqrt r_i}x_i\sqrt{r_i}\right)^2
=(x^t x)^2.$$

Answer (score 0):

You can work with the square root of $R$:
$$
x^Tx = x^TR^{1/2}R^{-1/2}x \le \|R^{1/2}x\|_2\cdot \|R^{-1/2}x\|_2 = (x^TRx)(x^TR^{-1}x).
$$